# How to change comment in a post using react redux and firebase connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-firestore

I'm trying to clone instagram and currently i'm stuck in comment section, when ever i try to add a comment, same comment is added to all the posts. i'm storing my comments in firestore and there it is getting saved correctly but i'm not able to figure out how to manage the state so that only those post should reflect changes where comments are added.

Here is the below code for the showcomments component and this will be used within another component.
can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      comment: {
      marginTop: "1rem",
    },
    postCaption: {
      ...theme.typography.postCaption,
    },
    username: {
      ...theme.typography.username,
    },
  }));


function ShowComments(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { comments } = props;

  const renderComments = () => {
    if (comments) {
      return comments.map((comment) => {
        return (
          <h3 key={comment.id}>
            {comment.username}{" "}
            <span className={classes.postCaption}>{comment.comment}</span>
          </h3>
        );
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(props.postId)}
      {renderComments()}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    comments: state.firestore.ordered.comments,
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect((props) => {
    return [
      {
        collection: "instagramPosts",
        doc: props.postId,
        subcollections: [{ collection: "comments" }],
        storeAs: "comments",
      },
    ];
  })
)(ShowComments);
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to say but how it works, does each post have own collection of comments and when you write comment do you update collection of the post related only to the post

Comment: yes every post has its own comments but while retreving the data oldpost commentsi are replaced by the new one, as a result every post is showing the same comments